# KML markers not showing in Google Maps API v3

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, tags, kml, markers

I'm trying to load a range of KML files into my new website which uses Google Maps API v3, however the icons are not showing up. It reverts to a standard Google icon, even though the icons I have added show up fine in Google Earth.
I honestly dont know what I'm doing, but through reading online I managed to reference my icon which I uploaded to Google+ in the html between all the href/href tags, so the html looks like this:

```
<Document>
    <name>Unsafe areas.KML</name>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin1500">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>0.6</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-be-8mm8S64M/U8ynZsmeHUI/AAAAAAAATi0/y8aTcpyZaYE/s846-no/icon_4627_red.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="0.5" y="0.5" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
        </IconStyle>
```

I put all my points (which have icons attached) in one folder and all my polylines in another folder. The polyline formatting seems to work OK, but it just loads a blue standard pin for the icon of points, rather than a warning sign that I reference here: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-be-8mm8S64M/U8ynZsmeHUI/AAAAAAAATi0/y8aTcpyZaYE/s846-no/icon_4627_red.png

Where am I going wrong, dont understand why it works in Google Earth but not in Google Maps API?

Here is a link to the KML file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sF6YtOhuTHdHIyaEJab045NDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe the icon is too large(846px × 846...yo really want to draw such an icon....note that scale is not supported in google maps)

Comment: Your KML [works with geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Unsafe_areas.KML), [the Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Unsafe_areas.KML) renders the icons as the default blue markers. Dr.Molle might be correct.

Comment: FYI, usually the Google Maps API KmlLayer (and all the Google Maps KML renders, which seem to use the same engine) resizes custom icons to 64x64. Perhaps this is too big for it to attempt that.

Comment: That was it, thank you. I re-sized the icons down to 64x64 and it worked fine....